# При отправке формы html с Python и использованием request пишет: AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'getlist'

Tags: python, html, post, get, request

@app.route("/update", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def update():

```
data = request.getlist("datasel")
met = request.getlist("met")
```

*html*

```
<form action="/update">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:230px">Обновить</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать MultiDict объект из Flask. Попробуйте:

```
data = request.form.getlist("datasel")
met = request.form.getlist("met")
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!